# Hard trigger/constraints making

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to database and I have a question about a table with triggers or maybe a check constraint. I'm using SQL Server Mangagement studio.

I have the following table:

```
create table item(
    startprice        char(5)          not null,
    description       char(22)         not null,
    start_date        char(10)         not null,
    end_date          char(10)         not null,
    indicator         char(3)          not null
```

);

What I'm trying to make is this trigger/constraint rule: `indicator` will get "no" if system date is earlier than `start_date` and `end_date`, and "yes" if system date is after `start_date`.

Comment: I think you'll need a trigger, because `CHECK` is used only to ensure that a field's value satisfies the constraint. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Which database are you using? Oracle? Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: I would suggest trigger, computed column or view, but sql syntax differs for each RDBMS.

Comment: I would suggest to change title to something like "How to create a trigger which computes column in SQL server (mssql)".

Comment: Side-note: I would **not** recommend using `char(22)` for `description`. The `char` datatype will always pad its column's contents to the defined length, e.g. **all** your strings will be padded with spaces to 22 characters. Makes it rather hard and unwieldy to use. `char(n)` is fine for **short** (3-5 characters) strings which are always that fixed length - ISO currency code, ISO country codes etc. - but it's **not** well suited for longer strings; use `varchar(22)` instead - only stores what's really entered into your column!

Comment: Do you have and ID column? That may be desired because sql server stores inserted/updated/deleted values in respetive pseudotables and there should be a way of retrieving that exact row

Comment: However, in your case, trigger can just update indicators for all rows with same combination of startdate-enddate as of the updated row. But this is certain overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple you have to use trigger with `before insert` option -

Following trigger is good to go in Oracle DB -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  item_insert_indicator 
BEFORE DELETE ON item 
For each row 
begin
if  :New.start_date > sysdate and :new.end_date > sysdate then 
   :New.indicator := 'no';
elsif :New.start_date < sysdate
   :New.indicator := 'yes';
end if;
end;
```

This is just for your reference. for your database you can change keywords accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If `indicator` is evaluated only by insertion, then I would suggest to go with saving sysdate in new column `created` and having `indicator` as [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE item ADD created datetime not null default getdate()

ALTER TABLE item ADD indicator AS 
    case when created < start_date then 'no' else 'yes' end
    PERSISTED
```

[Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) is also a good option:

```
CREATE TRIGGER item_indicator
ON item
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
   update inserted set indicator 
     = case when getdate() < start_date then 'no' else 'yes' end
GO
```

and also [create new view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) (if you persist sysdate in `created` column):

```
 create view item2 as 
   select ...
     , case when created < start_date then 'no' else 'yes' end as indicator
   from item
```

If you need to do lot of queries on `indicator` then I would go better with persisted computed column or trigger + adding index on `indicator`.

If the **value is computed with each update**, then trigger seems the most suitable.

None of these examples are tested in real case :)

Comment: this is alter table which would work for existing data .. but what about new data going to be insert into table?

Comment: As I know in sql server default value is computed on each insert if the value is not set (or null?), and on alter table alter table "add/change default" - for all null values. So it should work, but I strongly suggest to try out all cases ;)